# Handle consecutive button clicks in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Question: How to handle consecutive button clicks in jQuery. For example I am submitting the form to server but in the meantime user clicks button again then duplicate request has been generated for the same. How to handle this efficiently in jQuery.

HTML Code:

```
<a id="submitBtn" href="javascript:void(0);" 
   onclick="login.validateLogin();" 
   class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
var login = {   
  validateLogin:function(){
    $("#errormsg").hide();
    login.validate();
    if($('#loginForm').valid() ===  false){
      return;
    }

    $("#submitBtn").prop('onclick',null);

    /* Server request */               
   },
   validate:function(){
     $("#loginForm").validate({
       ignore:"",  
       submitHandler: function(form) { return false; }
     });           
   },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have the `.validate()` method inside a function like that.  The `.validate()` method is supposed to be called once and only used for initializing the plugin.

You should use a `type="submit"` button so that you can properly integrate with the plugin and enable/disable it much easier than trying to manually capture/deactivate/activate an anchor element.  (Use CSS on the `button` element to make it look exactly like your anchor element.)

Then use `.prop('disabled', 'disabled')` within the `submitHandler` to disable the button as soon as the properly validated form is submitted.

As you can see by the demo, most of your code was not needed as the plugin takes care of nearly everything automatically.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginForm").validate({  // <- initialize plugin on form
        ignore: [],  // <- proper way to set ignore to nothing
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
            alert('submitted');  // <- for demo
            return false;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form id="loginForm">
    <button id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Disable the `<submit>` button or any other button which on clicked, submits the form, so only first click gets counted and the end user is prevented from clicking it. It is also *semantic* way of doing as just unbinding any event associated with the button while still allowing to click, will in some way confuse the users.

```
$("#loginForm").validate({
    ignore: "",
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', true); // disable so it won't be clicked 
        return false;
    }
});
```